# window.open- name parameter does not work on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I tested it on IE. I am trying to open the URL in same tab, if exists. It does not work as expected if we use URL like (htp://www.google.com) and working if we use our domain page.

While it worked well for Firefox and chrome.

Following example does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction1() {
        window.open('http://www.google.com', 'f');
    }
    function myfunction2() {
        window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', 'f');
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a href="#" onclick='myfunction1();'>myfunction1</a> 
        <a href="#" onclick='myfunction2();'>myfunction2</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And Following example works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunction1() {
            window.open('WebForm1.aspx', 'f');
        }
        function myfunction2() {
            window.open('WebForm2.aspx', 'f');
        }
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a href="#" onclick='myfunction1();'>myfunction1</a>
        <a href="#" onclick='myfunction2();'>myfunction2</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.open` does not open a website in the same tab.

Comment: Not working as in, it is not opening a new tab with the URL specified or it is opening the URL in a new tab instead of the same tab?

Comment: It is opening the URL in a new tab instead of the same tab. It works on Chrome and Firefox and does not work on IE

Comment: In the Internet Options | General, there's a "Tabs" button. Click that button, and check/set, how IE should open tabs and pop-ups. And please, include your comment to Jason in your post, "not working" is not a proper problem description.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open in the same page, then you can change the location.href property.  If you would like to open in a new tab, in the same browser, then window.open works in IE9.

I used this in a new .html file, opened in IE9 and it worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction1() {
        window.open('http://www.google.com', 'f');
    }
    function myfunction2() {
        window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', 'f');
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a href="#" onclick='myfunction1();'>myfunction1</a> 
        <a href="#" onclick='myfunction2();'>myfunction2</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why was this down-voted? The question doesn't specify which version of IE he is using, currently, for IE9+ window.open(...) will open a new tab with a page.  His question is phrased in a way that suggests he wants window.open to open in the current tab, which won't work.  He needs to change the location.href property if that is his desire.

Comment: When I will click on first anchor then it should open it another tab. But when i will click on another anchor then it should be opened on the tab which was just created before. Because in window.open(strUrl,name) I am using same name property for two anchors.

Comment: Okay, I understand.  You click, window.open a new tab.  Then you click another anchor and want the previously created tab to load that url.  Not create a third tab.

Comment: I used this jsfiddle in IE9 and it does what you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/aZ4bj/

Comment: I gone through your link. It is working. Again I copied your code from jsfiddle and pasted it in my application, freshly created a new application and a page and it did not worked for IE9. I request you to please use it inside test application and test it.

Comment: @AmarMishra Jason's code really works as expected, but depending on how the Tabs options are set. Please just check the options for opening tabs/windows. You can't rely on IE opening a new tab or window as you wish, user can override your JS.

Comment: Jason's code works well when opening on jsfiddle(IE) but does not work when I really implement it in my test application. Just test it in any test application pls

Comment: I copied your exact code, just adding the head and doctype into a new .html file and opened in ie with no issue.  I appended my answer with the info.  What type of project are you trying to do this in? (for example, mvc asp.net web forms)?

Comment: Ok, so I created an MVC4 application, created a blank view with a single controller action.  I copied your exact code, directly into the view.  I then saved and ran the application in IE9 and both links work, just as they do in a blank .html file and as they do in JSFiddle.  Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: I am using IE10 and also tried by changing browsing mode to IE9, IE8, IE7. I also checked on another machine with only IE9 configured but did not worked.

Comment: Well, without your project, I can't recreate your issue, unfortunately.  My only point of note is that are there any scripting, security zone, or popup blocker settings done by your business that might change the expected behavior?  Also, are you using traditional asp.net (web forms) or asp.net mvc?

Comment: I tested it on simple .html file, asp.net web form 2010, asp.net MVC2 on three different machines in our office premises, but no success found. I don't think there would be any extra settings for popup / scripting done by our office administrator. One test is pending is on my personal computer. I will update you in next day.

Comment: Yeah, that is really odd.  Definitely respond back with your personal computer results.  I will try at home on my pc with IE 10 and 11 to verify as well.